# Azure Webjob fails after 4 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have 3 webjobs. 2 run continuously for several months now without any problem.
The 3rd one I recently created and is a triggered webjob and listens to my storage queue.
This works fine, except after 4 minutes the webjob crashes and the status is set to 'Failed'.

Looking at the error log I see this:

```
was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
```

But the whole idea is that the webjob will do its task when something is put on the queue, in the meantime, the webjob can go IDLE that is no problem.

It seems I'm missing the big picture. I did start the webjob in the portal. Was that wrong? Should I keep it on 'Ready'?

What is the correct workflow to create a webjob that listens to the queue, sleeps when it has nothing to do and wakes up again when something is put on the queue?

Comment: Is it deployed as a Triggered or Continuous WebJobs? ANd are you using the WebJob SDK?

Comment: why not use azure function?

Comment: Did you enabled the `Always On` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answering the questions:

- I deployed it as a Triggered WebJob
- I am using the WebJob SDK
- I'm not familiar with `Azure function`
- I enabled `Always On`

Now the solution. Yesterday evening I added `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` to the `Application settings` in the Azure Portal and set its value to 3600, which should mean 1 hour.
I also added this setting to my `<appSettings>` in `app.config` and just noticed my WebJob is still running (over 11 hours now). I just put something on the queue and it is nicely processed.

I'm not sure why it is now working but I'm glad it does ;)

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  I too am having the exact same problem you described where the entire job is failing after a few mins.  Basically, I run the job.  Put something on the queue.  Executes.  Then that queuejob stays idle for 121 seconds and then aborts.  Taking down the whole web job with it.  Increasing to timeout to 1 hour seems like it would just delay it to 1 hour instead of 121 seconds.  Sorry, this doesn't make any sense as a fix.  Do you have additional insight since this was 7 or 8 months ago?

Comment: Job should execute when item is placed on queue.  However, in my case the job finishes execution, but never "completes" as it just aborts 121 seconds later and then is marked as "failed" and crashes out the whole job so that it wont pick up anything else added to queue.  Makes no sense to me, and MS documentation is useless on this subject.  I documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728640/triggered-web-job-executing-completely-and-then-aborting-with-timeout-121-secon